# Bluestacks app player with BitDefender

Tags: windows-7, bluestacks

Is there any way to install BlueStacks app player on PC with BitDefender? When I try to install Bluestacks I get message: Bluestacks is not compatible with BitDefender. Installation will now abort. 
I try installing Bluestacks in new partition on hdd (I excluded this partition from scaning) and the same thing is happening. I have 32-bit Win 7 Pro.
What should I try to avoid this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Probably you just can't install both on the same computer.

Comment: Bluestacks has lots of bugs. You can use Genymotion. It is the best Android emulator available right now both for developers and normal users.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Bluestacks V4 with BD Total Security 2019 and it works fine.  However my Windows version is 10.

You should try disabling BD AV and all protection modules before installing Bluestacks.

A second option is to uninstall BD, install Bluestacks and then reinstall BD.

I have had to disable/uninstall BD many times to install other software.

You can also try installing an older version of Bluestacks.  But the latest version is definately compatible with Bit Defender.